# Advance search with elasticsearch and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I want to use ElasticSearch to search with multiple parameters (name, sex, age at a time).

what I've done so far is included elastic search in my model and added a as_indexed_json method for indexing and included relationship.

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :item

  validates :product_id, :item_id, :weight, presence: true
  validates :product_id, uniqueness: {scope: [:item_id] }

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    self.as_json({
      only: [:id],
      include: {
        product: { only: [:name, :price] },
        item: { only: :name },
      }
    })
  end

def self.search(query)
    # i'm sure this method is wrong I just don't know how to call them from their respective id's
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      query: {
        filtered: {
          filter: {
            bool: {
              must: [
                {
                  match: {
                    "product.name" => query  
                  }
                }
              ],
              must: [
                {
                  match: {
                    "item.name" => query
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    )
  end

end

User.import force: true
```

And In controller

```
def index
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
if params[:search].present? and params[:product_name].present?
  @users = User.search(params[:product_name]).records
end
if params[:search].present? and params[:product_price].present?
  @users = User.search(params[:product_price]).records
end
if params[:search].present? and params[:item].present?
  if @users.present?
    @users.search(item: params[:item], product: params[:product_name]).records
  else
    @users = User.search(params[:item]).records
  end
end
```

end

There are basically 3 inputs for searching with product name , product price and item name, This is what i'm trying to do like if in search field only product name is present then

```
@users = User.search(params[:product_name]).records
```

this will give me records but If user inputs another filter say product price or item name in another search bar then it's not working. any ideas or where I'm doing wrong :/ stucked from last 3 days

Comment: Perhaps are you doing an 'AND' search and no results actually match the query? 

`price:100 AND name;'product 1'` and no product with said name and price is found.

Comment: Try to activate the query logging and check them against your documents: `Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true`

Comment: @Raphael yea i'm performing an 'AND' search and i'm sure that the price:100 AND name;'product 1' exist in my database. I just have no idea how should I get all the params in the search method, One more thing when I hide my search method and just go with single search e.g search only with product name then it works fine but after I uncomment the search method and try to do single search nothing works. Can you please be more specific and detailed as i'm totally new to elastic search.

Comment: That command is going to allow you to see in log the lucene query the gem is assembling and sending to ES. That will make it easier for you to debug.

Comment: @Raphael do I need to implement search method if I want to search with multiple fields or the as_indexed_json method is enough and yea one more thing Do I need to add as_indexed_json method in associated models also like in product and item too ?